# How to index a specific column to perform field comparison calculations?

Tags: indexing, calculated-columns, qlikview, qliksense, columnsorting

Given the following table:

```
|   A  |     B      | holdingtemp1 | holdingTemp2 | holdingtemp3 | holdingTemp4 |  idx |
| Grits| 7:06:24 AM | 180.199      |      -       |      -       |      -       |   0  |
|      | 8:35:56 AM |      -       | 174.30       |      -       |      -       |   1  | 
|      | 9:25:18 AM |      -       |      -       |      182     |      -       |   2  |
|      | 10:02:0 AM |      -       |      -       |      -       |      180     |   3  |
```

How to properly index column `B` to perform field comparisons in order to implement conditional logic where each temperature recording must be taken within a two hour interval relative to the previous recording, such that:

```
if(B[0] + 2 > B[1], green(), red()) // 9:06 > 8:35, turns cell green
if(B[1] + 2 > B[2], green(), red()) // 10:35 > 9:25, turns cell green
```

Edit:

Found the right [function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/February2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/Peek.htm) to use for this implementation, but `peak()` is returning `4:43:21 AM` for all records with

`Peek('B', 0) as peekB, // 4:43:21 AM`

and `5:11:03 AM` with
`Peek('B', 1) as peekB, //  5:11:03 AM`

If so, does `peek()` fetch the field value of the *preloaded* or *postloaded* data?

Comment: the second argument in `peek` (0 in your case) is optional. With the second argument `peek` will return the value of the row specified. If you just want the value for the row above then use it without the second argument `Peek('B') as peekB`